# Perl Regex to match strings and numbers inside a file

Tags: regex, perl

Hi I am new to perl and trying to write a regex to find a match for specific number range and strings in a line inside the file, i need to find the lines("Document has 15  rows and 2 columns").

I know I am missing something, but the code I have tried so far is :

```
if(/^[a-zA-Z\d]+(has\s[1-9][0-9]$)\srows.*columns/)
{
 print "$_\n";
}
```

It would be really helpful if anyone let me know what is wrong here!

Comment: Are you trying to match the word 'Document', or does Document represent some file name?

Comment: Document here is just a word and not the file name, also i just need to look for the words "rows" and "columns".

Answer (score 3):

The other answers here are good, but to explain what was wrong with the regex you used:

```
if(/^[a-zA-Z\d]+(has\s[1-9][0-9]$)\srows.*columns/)
```

First problem: the expression does not specify any whitespace between the beginning of the string and the word `has`, so there is no way for this pattern to match the space in `Document has...`

Second problem: the `$` character in a regular expression means "match if the line ends here."  It's almost always a mistake to use the `$` anchor in the middle of a regex; the only way this would match would be in a multiline string like

```
Documenthas 15
rows and 7 columns
```

Making those two changes to your expression makes it work:

```
if(/^[a-zA-Z\d]+\s(has\s[1-9][0-9])\srows.*columns/)
{
 print "$_\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy regex to use:

```
/Document has [0-9]+ row(s?) and [0-9]+ column(s?)/
```

If the `s` is only used when there is more than one row/column

Comment: Thanks! this code worked, just one more thing, how can i check for the rows >1000 here?

Comment: The expression matches as many digits as there are. Four or five is nowhere near any applicable limit.

Comment: @Sri For that, you will need to use an expression that "captures" the number of rows and columns mentioned. Two of the other answers given here illustrate how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to capture the numbers.

```
if ( /^Document has (\d+) rows and (\d+) columns/ ) {
    my $rows = $1;
    my $cols = $2;
```

Comment: Though not a big issue, but `\d`, is locale supporting as far as I recall, and includes also non-latin digits, but I might be wrong

Comment: @nrathaus: how is this an issue at all?

Comment: 1) `\d` is slower, 2) there might be non-digits there, which it would capture - anyway I said its NOT a big issue

Comment: I'd need to see some proof that `\d` is slower, but even if it is, so what?  The amount of time spent on `\d+` vs. `[0-9]` is going to be dwarfed by the amount of time reading from disk.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $line = "Document has 15 rows and 2 columns"

if ($line =~ /^Document has (\d+) rows? and (\d+) columns?/)
{
    print "rows = $1\n";
    print "cols = $2\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the number of rows, use this:

```
if (/(\d+)\s+rows/) {
   print "$1\n";
}
```

If you want rows and columns (and they are always in that order), use:

```
if (/(\d+)\s+rows\s+and\s+(\d+)\s+columns/) {
     print "$1 rows and $2 columns\n";
}
```

If you think it is necessary, you can be more restrictive if you need to: restricting the number of digits, forcing non-leading zeros, etc.

Also, I assume you are either using "-n" on the command line or have a loop around this.